# How to debug falcon app on windows and pycharm?

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, falcon

there is a way to debug a falcon app on windows? I'm using Pycharm.

I use waitress to run from the command line, but I have no idea how to debug my source code.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't get the question. I use Pycharm to develop a falcon REST API on windows. No problems in debugging whatsoever.
You just need to set a *run configuration* by setting the *Script path* to point to the file with the `waitress.serve` line and then launch it as *Debug* instead of *Run*.

In my case the file looks like this:

```
from api_falcon.app import api as application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    import waitress
    waitress.serve(application, host=os.getenv('MYAPI_WSGI_HOST', '0.0.0.0'), port=os.getenv('MYAPI_WSGI_PORT', '8080'))
```

Comment: Thanks, @Alessandro but I choose another framework to work with. As I mentioned in the last comment, in this hurried world with a bast of options out there, I decided by another framework

Answer (score 0):

I have used pycharm 2018 and I have not found any support for debug falcon app(maybe I could be wrong ). What I have done is make a different file on same directory and put all function over there and debug that file as normal python script or. May be you can use print or kind of unit test to test your code.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. @Dip Ghosh. Unfortunately, situations like that are enough to discard or choose a framework. This days, the ability to debugging is a must-have functionality.